# Recover a lost partition on a USB flash drive (after using it for boot)

Tags: usb, boot, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

I used [wintoflash](http://wintoflash.com/download/en/) to create a bootable device from my USB flash drive.

It had 8GB, and now I can see only 2GB.

I tried using win 7 default disk management utility but it can't merge the partitions.

Any advice how to do it ?

Comment: Was the drive partitioned or do you only see a 2 GB flash drive?

Comment: It was partitioned by the software. I now can't un partition it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy off important data, then delete both partitions, then format it.

Comment: Thanks you. How do you delete a partition on a USB? (the software on win 7 doesn't offer it - it does only for normal HD)

Comment: The partitions should show up in Disk Management (it does for my usb drives), delete them there.